# Delphi WebSphere MQ Remote Connect

Tags: delphi, ibm-mq

I am writing an application in Delphi to connect to remote MQ Server and get messages.
I installed a MQ Server on my comp and wrote a test application.
All well Connect,Open,Put,Get,.. all works well.
Then I tried to connect to remote MQ by changing address, it works but not correctly, it works with local MQ still and get info from local. not switched to other remote server!!!!
My source is as bellow, What I should do? Thanks

```
var
  QMgrName    : MQCHAR48;
  ConnectOpts : TMQCNO;
  ClientConn  : TMQCD;
  Compcode    : MQLONG;
  Reason      : MQLONG;
begin
  StrPCopy(QMgrName, AQueueManager+#0);
  ConnectOpts.StrucId := MQCNO_STRUC_ID;
  ConnectOpts.Version := MQCNO_VERSION_1;
  ConnectOpts.Options := MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING;
  ConnectOpts.ClientConnOffset := 0;
  ConnectOpts.ClientConnPtr := @ClientConn;

  with ClientConn do begin
    StrPCopy(ClientConn.ConnectionName, format('%s(%s)'#0, [AIP,APort]));
    Version := MQCD_VERSION_6;
    ChannelType := MQCHT_CLNTCONN;
    TransportType := MQXPT_TCP;
    Desc := '';
    QMgrName := '';
    XmitQName := '';
    ShortConnectionName := '';
    MCAName := '';
    ModeName := '';
    TpName := '';
    BatchSize := 50;
    DiscInterval := 6000;
    ShortRetryCount := 10;
    ShortRetryInterval := 60;
    LongRetryCount := 999999999;
    LongRetryInterval := 1200;
    SecurityExit := '';
    MsgExit := '';
    SendExit := '';
    ReceiveExit := '';
    SeqNumberWrap := 999999999;
    MaxMsgLength := 4194304;
    PutAuthority := MQPA_DEFAULT;
    DataConversion := MQCDC_NO_SENDER_CONVERSION;
    SecurityUserData := '';
    MsgUserData := '';
    SendUserData := '';
    ReceiveUserData := '';
    UserIdentifier := '';
    Password := '';
    MCAUserIdentifier := '';
    MCAType := MQMCAT_PROCESS;
    ConnectionName := '';
    RemoteUserIdentifier := '';
    RemotePassword := '';
    MsgRetryExit := '';
    MsgRetryUserData := '';
    MsgRetryCount := 10;
    MsgRetryInterval := 1000;
    HeartbeatInterval := 1;
    BatchInterval := 0;
    NonPersistentMsgSpeed := MQNPMS_FAST;
    StrucLength := MQCD_LENGTH_6;
    ExitNameLength := MQ_EXIT_NAME_LENGTH;
    ExitDataLength := MQ_EXIT_DATA_LENGTH;
    MsgExitsDefined := 0;
    SendExitsDefined := 0;
    ReceiveExitsDefined := 0;
    MsgExitPtr := nil;
    MsgUserDataPtr := nil;
    SendExitPtr := nil;
    SendUserDataPtr := nil;
    ReceiveExitPtr := nil;
    ReceiveUserDataPtr := nil;
    ClusterPtr := nil;
    ClustersDefined := 0;
    NetworkPriority := 0;
    LongMCAUserIdLength := 0;
    LongRemoteUserIdLength := 0;
    LongMCAUserIdPtr := nil;
    LongRemoteUserIdPtr := nil;
//    MCASecurityId := MQSID_NONE_ARRAY;
//    RemoteSecurityId := MQSID_NONE_ARRAY;
  end;
  MQCONNX(@QMgrName, ConnectOpts, HConn,Compcode,Reason);
  if CompCode <> MQCC_OK then
    raise Exception.Create(format('MQCONNX Fail, Completion Code: %d, Reason: %d',[CompCode,Reason]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet doesn't show the `uses` statement.  According to [the MA7Q docs](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/ma7q.pdf),

> The SupportPac contains two files called 'MQI.PAS' and 'MQIC.PAS'.
>   These are Pascal sources that should be placed somewhere in the Search
>   Path of Delphi to be included in your Pascal program. The way to
>   include it is like using any unit in Pascal:
>
> uses MQI;
>   or
>   uses MQIC;

The `MQI` is the bindings mode (shared memory) connection and the `MQIC` is the client connection over the network stack.

It is possible to have both available and let the application determine which to use at run-time.  According to the [WMQ Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fg12050_.htm):

> If you are linking to the mqm library, then a standard server
>   connection using the default bind type is attempted first. If the
>   underlying server library failed to load, a client connection is
>   attempted instead.

This suggests to me that you have both libraries in the path and the connection is finding the local QMgr first and ignoring the client connection parameters, or perhaps that you are using the MQI library where you want the MQIC library.  Make sure the MQIC library is in the path and change your `uses` statement.

If switching the library does not alone solve the problem, consider specifying  `MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING` instead of `MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING`.

Answer (score 3):

Verify the connection by testing with some other app.  When I was doing MQ, I'd always start with one of their C examples for get/put. Get that working, and THEN worry about whether or not my program works.  Your problem is likely to do with the connection string, authentication, firewall, etc., so until you verify connectivity, your code is irrelevant.

Update:  If you get an error from the stock MQ sample apps, google for the name of the sample app plus the error code!

Comment: Good point.  Look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ 7.5\tools\c\Samples` (the default location for WMQ v7.5 on Windows but may be different on any particular install or different version) for compiled test programs like `amqsputc`, `amqsgetc` and `amqsbcgc`.

Comment: Thanks. I started by test app "amqscnxc" for connect to remote server. I runned as amqscnxc -x 192.168.1.3" but get error 2035. it is related to security! how can I set remote (windows) UserName/Password?